# How to copy a local repository without connection to the original

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I am trying to copy a local repository to another folder. I do not want the green check mark on it or any other sub-folders. The reason is because I need to commit that folder to another remote repository.

I'm not sure if that is possible.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the SVN "export" command is what you're looking for.  [Here's how to do
it under TortoiseSVN.](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html)